# Compare columns of different excel using python

Tags: python

I need to compare particular column between two excel sheet and if value matches then we need to replace the second column value of second excel sheet  into the first column of first excel sheet for eg

First sheet column

```
I'd 

Tas-0001
Tas-0002
```

Second sheet column

```
I'd         Name

Tas-0001    tin-90876
Tas-0002    tin-56883
```

So i need to compare both excel based on id column and if it's matches need to replace the name column of second excel sheet into first column of first excel sheet

So final answer will be like

```
Id
Tin-90876
Tin-56883
```

I am trying using python panda dataframe but not able to achieve it.

Comment: Please include code of what you've tried so far and why it isn't working. Is there a specific error you need help with? Is the output not what you expected? etc.

Comment: So, you read the second file into a dictionary that maps Id to Name.  Then, the job becomes very easy.